# ¿Como puedo usar el form-data en api gateway dentro de aws?

Tags: api, aws, formdata

Dentro de las api que uso para una aplicación, deberia usar form-data para poder hacer posts de archivos o informacion de un usuario, pero no entiendo del todo como hacer la estructura de la api en api rest, se que hay parametros como multipart/form-data para usar form data y BODY raw con los application/json.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y queria saber si lo hago de la manera correta o si debo poner alguna estructura en el requestbody de la api
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien sabe me gustaria un poco de orientación, no se si lo estoy formulando bien.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco más me pude guiar por dos documentos de aws, si alguien ve esta pregunta ojala le ayude si se topo con lo mismo que yo x3.

*Form-data*
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

*Subir archivos*
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html